# read rows of ints from a file in C

Tags: c

how can I read rows of ints from a txt file in C.
input.txt

3

5 2 3

1

2 1 3 4

the first 3 means there are 3 lines in all.
I write a c++ version using cin cout sstream
but I wonder how can I make it in C using fscanf or other c functions.
I need to handle each line of integers separately.

I know I can use getline to read the whole line into a buffer, then parse the string buffer to get the integers.
Can I just use fscanf?

Comment: You should read the documentation of [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html), [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html), [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) ...

Comment: If you have not tried anything then go through some tutorials or books.

Comment: `fscanf(file,"%d",&integer);` does the trick. Add this in a loop to read several `int`s.

Comment: @CooGuy: but `fscanf` alone does not handle end-of-line concerns; and the result of `fscanf` should be tested

Comment: @CoolGuy I do this but I need to handle each line rather than handle them together.

Comment: The `%n` format specifier for `sscanf` might be relevant.. I voted to close this question because it is too broad and without any code.

Comment: @JaruxussTong: "Can I just use fscanf?"? The answer is in the documentation (and probably no). Why not use `getline` and parse the line with `strtol` or `sscanf` ?

Comment: @JaraxussTong , Then use `fgets(line,sizeof line,file);sscanf(line,"%d",&integer);`. Add more `%d` to extract more integers from `line`. Also check the return values of all the functions mentioned.(That includes `fscanf` if you want to use it)

Comment: You can also simply use `strtol` while there is a returned value for `endptr` and avoid using `sscanf` altogether.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin , Why avoid `sscanf`?

Comment: No reason in particular. However, with multiple values in each line you will use either `strtok`, or walk a pointer and pass the values to `strtol` (or `atoi`), so why not just use `strtol` to begin with and take advantage of the value returned by `endptr` to test whether additional values remain in line. Just always found it more efficient.

Comment: sscanf doesn't advance a pointer easily and there are conflicting directives on whether %n affects the return value of sscanf or not.  Maybe that issue was addressed in more recent iterations of the C standard.

Answer (score 3):

What you ultimately want to do is free yourself from having to worry about the format of your inputfile. You want a routine that is flexible enough to read each row and parse the integers in each row and allocate memory accordingly. That greatly improves the flexibility of your routine and minimizes the amount of recoding required.

As you can tell from the comments there are many, many, many valid ways to approach this problem. The following is a quick hack at reading all integers in a file into an `array`, printing the array, and then cleaning up and freeing the memory allocated during the program. (note: the checks for reallocating are shown in comments, but omitted for brevity).

Note too that the storage for the array is allocated with `calloc` which allocates and sets the memory to `0`. This frees you from the requirement of keeping a persistent row and column count. You can simply iterate over values in the array and stop when you encounter an uninitialized value. Take a look over the code and let me know if you have any questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MROWS 100
#define MCOLS 20

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.  usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed for '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *line = NULL;          /* NULL forces getline to allocate  */
    size_t n = 0;               /* max chars to read (0 - no limit) */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;           /* number of chars actually read    */
    int **array = NULL;         /* array of ptrs to array of int    */
    size_t ridx = 0;            /* row index value                  */
    size_t cidx = 0;            /* col index value                  */
    char *endptr = NULL;        /* endptr to use with strtol        */

    /* allocate MROWS (100) pointers to array of int */
    if (!(array = calloc (MROWS, sizeof *array))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: array allocation failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line in file */
    while ((nchr = getline (&line, &n, fp)) != -1) 
    {
        /* strip newline or carriage return (not req'd) */
        while (line[nchr-1] == '\r' || line[nchr-1] == '\n')
            line[--nchr] = 0;

        if (!nchr)      /* if line is blank, skip */
            continue;

        /* allocate MCOLS (20) ints for array[ridx] */
        if (!(array[ridx] = calloc (MCOLS, sizeof **array))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: array[%zd] allocation failed\n", ridx);
            return 1;
        }

        cidx = 0;       /* reset cidx               */
        char *p = line; /* assign pointer to line   */

        /* parse each int in line into array    */
        while ((array[ridx][cidx] = (int)strtol (p, &endptr, 10)) && p != endptr)
        {
            /* checks for underflow/overflow omitted */

            p = endptr; /* increment p      */
            cidx++;     /* increment cidx   */
            /* test cidx = MCOLS & realloc here */
        }
        ridx++;         /* increment ridx   */

        /* test for ridx = MROWS & realloc here */
    }

    /* free memory and close input file */
    if (line) free (line);
    if (fp) fclose (fp);

    printf ("\nArray:\n\n  number of rows with data: %zd\n\n", ridx);

    /* reset ridx, output array values */
    ridx = 0;
    while (array[ridx])
    {
        cidx = 0;
        while (array[ridx][cidx])
        {
            printf ("  array[%zd][%zd] = %d\n", ridx, cidx, array[ridx][cidx]);
            cidx++;
        }
        ridx++;
        printf ("\n");
    }

    /* free allocated memory */
    ridx = 0;
    while (array[ridx])
    {
        free (array[ridx]);
        ridx++;
    }
    if (array) free (array);

    return 0;
}
```

**input file**

```
$ cat dat/intfile.txt
3

5 2 3

1

2 1 3 4
```

**program output**

```
$ ./bin/readintfile dat/intfile.txt

Array:

  number of rows with data: 4

  array[0][0] = 3

  array[1][0] = 5
  array[1][1] = 2
  array[1][2] = 3

  array[2][0] = 1

  array[3][0] = 2
  array[3][1] = 1
  array[3][2] = 3
  array[3][3] = 4
```

Comment: +1 , Nice answer! I learnt a lot from it. But I've never seen `%zd` before. Isn't the right format specifier for `size_t` `%zu`?

Comment: Yes, it seems in my haste I appended it to a decimal format specifier instead of unsigned. Good catch. (although, I'm not sure it made much difference here) But from a consistency standpoint `%zu` it is.

Answer (score 1):

In C (not C++) you should combine `fgets` with `sscanf` function.

**EDIT:**

But as an answer for the question "Can I just use fscanf?"

try this example (where usage of `fgetc` allows using `fscanf` instead of `fgets`+`sscanf`):

```cpp
    int lnNum = 0;
    int lnCnt = 0; // line counter
    int ch; // single character
    // read number of lines
    fscanf(f, "%d", &lnNum);
    if(lnNum < 1)
    {
        return 1;  // wrong line number
    }
    // reading numbers line by line
    do{
        res = fscanf(f, "%d", &num);
        // analyse res and process num
        // .... 

        // check the next character
        ch = fgetc(f);
        if(ch == '\n')
        {
            lnCnt++; // one more line is finished
        }
    } while (lnNum > lnCnt && !feof(f) );
```

**NOTE:** This code will work when your file has only numbers separated by single '\n' or spaces, for case of letters or combinations as `number   \n` (space before newline) it becomes unstable

Comment: Why use `fgets` (which reads a fixed length buffer) instead of `getline` (which accepts very long lines)?

Comment: Not to mention `getline` returns the number of characters actually read, which is another distinct advantage.

Comment: Oh, it's just exactly what I want.

Comment: you are welcome, but remember about "NOTE" after example

Comment: If you use `num = strtol(str, endptr, 10)` to read your numbers, you can use the value of endptr to skip over lots of spaces or newlines.