# Reading Integers in from a file, line by line, separated by whitespace

Tags: c

I'm quite stuck and not sure where to begin with the project I'm working on. The idea is to read data (integers) in from an input file. We're supposed to read each integer in one at a time, line by line. We cannot use arrays. Only loops. Additionally, we should be ignoring lines with <2 integers (i.e. lines 1 and 3 in the example below.)

The input file is formatted like this:

```
3
5 -5 0
5
1 -2 3 -4 5
```

This is what I have so far (snippet):

```c
while (fscanf(inFileHandle, "%d", &num) == 1) {
   //read in one number, add to sum
   sum += num;

   if (num > highest) {
      highest = num;
   }
   else if (num < lowest) {
      lowest = num;
   }
}

/* while ((c = (char)getc(inFileHandle)) != EOF) {
      if (c == ' ') {
         printf("space found");
      }
      else if (c == '\n') { //newline reached
      }
      else {
         printf("int found");
      }

   }*/

fclose(inFileHandle);
```

With the data that gets read in, we are supposed to do calculations, but that isn't the point of this question.

As you can see I have a while loop that uses fscanf to read in an integer, but that's not entirely what I want. I only want to read in integers if the line has two or more integers (like lines 2 and 4 in the input file).

I also tried reading in one character at a time with getc(), and then checking the individual char "c", but I hit a dead end with that idea.

What's the best way to begin?

If anything is unclear, let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read rows of ints from a file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871314/read-rows-of-ints-from-a-file-in-c)

Comment: You cannot easily use `fscanf()` for this because of the requirement that you ignore lines with fewer than two integers.  `fscanf()` treats all whitespace separating input fields the same, including newlines.  You could read a line at a time via `fgets()`, and then employ `sscanf()`, but because your input format is pretty simple, it might in some ways indeed be easier to write a parser that operates character by character.

Comment: Just to fully understand your question: If a line has 5 ints, you must read all 5 ints, right?

Comment: What are you supposed to do with the `int`s you read (and do not ignore)?

Comment: Yes, as long as there are two or more integers on a line, they should be read in.

Comment: Your commented out loop looks like the way forward - just need to have it parse the numbers and track how many there are per line etc...

Comment: As far as what we're supposed to do with the integers that get read in, we are supposed to do simple calculations like finding  the sum, lowest number, the highest number, and finding the mean.

Comment: It now occurs to me that if you cannot use arrays *at all* then you cannot use `fgets()`, because you must provide a `char` array for it to read the line into.  Technically, you cannot use the `scanf` family of functions either, because you must provide the format as a `char` array (strings, including those designated by string literals, are arrays of `char`).  Perhaps your instructor will ignore that technicality, but the surest way to fulfill all the requirements would be by parsing character by character.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop will scan two items an int and a char. When the outer loop scans an int and a space, the inner loop will set the variables and continue scanning until an int and newline is scanned.

```
char ws = ' ';
int num = 0;

while ( result = fscanf ( inFileHandle, "%d%c", &num, &ws)) {
    if ( EOF == result) {
        break;
    }
    if ( 2 == result && ' ' == ws) {//scanned an int an a space
        sum = num;
        highest = num;
        lowest = num;
        while ( 2 == fscanf ( inFileHandle, "%d%c", &num, &ws)) {
            sum += num;
            if ( highest < num) {
                highest = num;
            }
            if ( lowest > num) {
                lowest = num;
            }
            if ( '\n' == ws) {//quit when a newline is scanned
                break;
            }
        }
        printf ( "sum is %d\n", sum);
        printf ( "highest is %d\n", highest);
        printf ( "lowest is %d\n", lowest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to use arrays (including strings which are char arrays), you'll have to read the file one char at the time and build the integer values manually. To do that you need a number of state variables to keep track on the progress.

It could be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
  int max = INT_MIN;
  int min = INT_MAX;
  int current;
  int numbersOnThisLine = 0;
  int parsingNumber = 0;
  int negative;
  int number = 0;
  int firstNumber;


  FILE* f = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
  if (!f)
  {
    printf("file error\n");
    return 1;
  }

  while ((current = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
  {
    switch (current)
    {

      case '-':
          negative = 1;
          break;

      case ' ':
          if (parsingNumber)
          {
            if (negative) number = -number;
            printf("Found %d\n", number);
            ++numbersOnThisLine;
            if (numbersOnThisLine == 1)
            {
              firstNumber = number;
            }
            if (numbersOnThisLine >= 2)
            {
              if (firstNumber > max) max = firstNumber;
              if (firstNumber < min) min = firstNumber;
              if (number > max) max = number;
              if (number < min) min = number;
            }
          }
          parsingNumber = 0;
          number = 0;
          negative = 0;
          break;

      case '\n':
          if (parsingNumber)
          {
            if (negative) number = -number;
            printf("Found %d\n", number);
            ++numbersOnThisLine;
            if (numbersOnThisLine >= 2)
            {
              if (number > max) max = number;
              if (number < min) min = number;
            }
          }
          numbersOnThisLine = 0;
          parsingNumber = 0;
          number = 0;
          negative = 0;
          break;

      default:
          if (current > '9' || current < '0')
          {
            printf("Illegal file format\n");
            fclose(f);
            return 1;
          }
          parsingNumber = 1;
          number = 10 * number + (current - '0');
          break;
    }
  }
  fclose(f);

  printf("min=%d max=%d\n", min, max);
  return 0;
}
```

With numbers.txt as:

```
-12343
5 -5 -11 0
555
444 -2 343 -4 7
```

the output is:

```
Found -12343
Found 5
Found -5
Found -11
Found 0
Found 555
Found 444
Found -2
Found 343
Found -4
Found 7
min=-11 max=444
```

**BTW** The code above actually uses char arrays (aka strings) in the `printf` - if you must avoid that also, you can use `putc` for printing.